# How to implement MSI (multi-source inventory) in Magento2.2.3 project?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento2.2.3

***Problem:*** I need to implement Global inventory management in magento 2.2.3. so that inventory can be synchronize from various sales channel like source(ecommerce marketplace example: amazon,flipkart.. others) and ERP (enterprise software for accounting , tax ).
[image]

***What I tried:***

- **catalogInventoryStockRegistryV1**

PUT /V1/products/{productSku}/stockItems/{itemId}

```
http://magentodomain.com/rest/V1/products/sku-100/stockItems/1
```

- **catalogProductRepositoryV1**

PUT /V1/products/{sku}

> Inventory can be update simultaneously from various sales channel and ERP through API.??

**Reference:**

https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi

https://www.slideshare.net/maghamed/multi-source-inventory-msi-in-magento-2

Anyone implement it successfully??

**Solution:**  Finding? still need to be write.

Comment: have you any progress on that?

Comment: @Alexey working on that .. not completed yet

Answer (score 2):

You can easily implement global inventory management in Magento 2.3 and your inventory can be synchronized from various sales channels.

MSI offers excellent support to the merchants controlling their single or multi-channel inventories and sales channels. It is designed especially for Magento store owners facilitate in managing their multi sources of inventory from the Magento 2 admin panel.

Until now, eCommerce store owners did faced many problems in managing multi inventory but now it’s all solved as MSI is a powerful tool facilitates in managing inventory in multi source with Magento store.

For detailed information about the same query feel free to visit [https://i-verve.com/blog/magento-2-multi-source-inventory-features.](https://i-verve.com/blog/magento-2-multi-source-inventory-features)